# Java how and when exactly is the paint() method called?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

I have been told many times that the paint() method will be called as and when required when I extend my class to JFrame but for eg. in the code the paint method is not being called and I don't see any rectangle drawn.

I even tried to call paint method inside the constructor (which I created) and then creating an obejct for the class in main but I got a NullPointerException

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFirstDrawing extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame w = new JFrame("Hello World");
        w.setTitle("My First Drawing");
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setSize(500,500);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(40, 40, 100, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: You created a new `JFrame`, not a `MyFirstDrawing `.

Comment: actually I did that too but nothing happened in the output so I deleted that line. Also I am a beginner so I did not know what to do with that object.

Comment: Don't override paint() on a JFrame!

Comment: Creating a subclass of JFrame and overriding one of its methods does not override that same method in all JFrame objects.  It only overrides the method for instances of your specific subclass.  Your code is not creating any instances of `MyFirstDrawing`.

Comment: That doesn't change my output.

Answer (score 2):

You have two frames:

1. You extend a JFrame and override the paint() method, but that frame is never made visible so the paint() method is never invoked.
2. Then you create a new JFrame which you make visible, but this frame has no custom painting so you just see the frame.

In any case this is NOT the way to do custom painting. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintCompnent(...)` of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples that you can customize.

The tutorial example will show you a better way to create your class so there is no need to extend a JFrame. Follow the tutorial example.

Comment: Don't forget, it's actually really important to call `super.paintComponent(g)` when overriding the `paintComponent()` method.  Otherwise, unpredictable painting may occur

Comment: I will definitely go through the examples but out of curiosity what would be a workaround 1. to get the frame that I made visible to have the painting inside it and 2. to use the JFrame I extended to draw my painting.

Comment: `Don't forget, it's actually really important to call super.paintComponent(g) when` - yes, and that is why my suggestion is to start with the working example found in the tutorial so you learn proper technique.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava, `but out of curiosity what would be a workaround` - don't waste your time on a workaround. Spend you time productively and understand how the painting process works. Read the tutorial, modify the code. Once you understand the code, then you can answer this question yourself. There is no shortcut to learning, and I will not promote poor code or design because then you get lazy and don't do it properly.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. I notice you haven't done this for any of your previous questions either.

Comment: I don't think I accept your answer. I still don't clearly understand when paint() method is called and my question remains unanswered. What you did here was change the question instead of answering it. It may be poor code but still I want to know how to make it work.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava, `I still don't clearly understand when paint() method is called` - because you don't listen to people. In your opening sentence you stated `I have been told many times that the paint() method will be called as and when required` - so you already have the answer. Why should we repeat the answer again when you don't listen the first time? It gets called when the component needs to repainted, for example when the frame is made visible, or the frame is resized.  We can't state every situation when it happens. What don't you understand about that???

Comment: `my question remains unanswered.` - no it was answered. The tutorial explains it. I don't have time to retype the tutorial so it is up to you to do reading yourself. If you have a specific question about the tutorial, then I can answer that. If you want the real technical details about how painting works then you can read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html). Again we can't guess what you find so confusing, so all we can do is provide resources for you to read. Then you ask a specific question about a sentence you don't understand!

Comment: Okay good I am reading the tutorial. I don't find any tutorials on swing without a GUI buider? Can you suggest some?

Comment: The tutorial has nothing to do about a GUI builder, The tutorial is about Swing basics. The code can be downloaded and copied into any editor.

Comment: @camickr I think you are giving me off topic answers as according to stack overflow recommending a book, tool, or software library, tutorial or other offsite resource are considered as off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: And I know the question has nothing to do with a gui builder but the Oracle tutorial is. It's using net beans as a gui builder which I don't like. I don't like to drag and drop things.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava, no the Oracle tutorial has nothing to do with net beans. It is a tutorial that you can read and then download the working code. Once again, you haven't listened to the suggestion. You've been given the answer to your original question. I told you that you don't make the frame with the custom painting visible, so how do you expect to see the painting??? I specifically stated the tutorial has nothing to do with net beans. You just download the code to any editor then compile and test it however you want. Don't forget to "accept" the answer!!!